# TypeScript: How to define the type when pass component in props in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Here's the code sample and the JS version is working correctly.

The issue I encountered happening in TS :

```
import React from 'react'

class Parent extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <Child Cpnt={<Header title='Header' />} />
        /* TS error on Cpnt */
      )
    }
  }

interface ChildProps {
    Cpnt: React.ComponentClass
}

class Child extends React.Component <ChildProps> {
    render () {
        const { Cpnt } = this.props
        return (
            <div>
                {{Cpnt}}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

interface HeaderProps {
    title: string
}

class Header extends React.Component <HeaderProps> {
    render () {
        const { title } = this.props
        return (
            <p>{title}</p>
        )
    }
}
```

I got an error on `<Child Cpnt`

```
[ts]
Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<{}, any>'.
  Type 'Element' provides no match for the signature 'new (props: {}, context?: any): Component<{}, any, any>'. [2322]
```

What type should I defind here?

Comment: try `React.ReactElement`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A React "renderable" is not `React.ComponentClass` but `React.ReactNode`.

Ask for `React.ReactNode` in your `Cpnt` prop.

Comment: `React.ReactNode` worked, but got new TS error: `JSX element type 'Tag' does not have any construct or call signatures.`

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `<Header title='header' />` which is a React Element not `Header` which is a Component Class.